# HLookup Function to Find the Next Smallest Number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that is takes two variables and looks for the closes match (rounding down) to the numbers, however, despite having set my HLookup statement to True, it is not finding the match.

Here is what my code looks like `center_wavelength_value` and `sweeprate` are both set as `Double` defined in a Sub where this function is called. They are set correctly when I was debugging. For testing purposes, I have `sweeprate = 50` and `center_wavelength_value = 1220` which is not a direct value in the lookup table, however since it is not an exact match it should round down and find the cell that of `center_wavelength = 1060` and `sweeprate = 50` however it is not. Its also not throwing an errors so I am unsure why this is happening. If anyone has any suggestions to fix it that would be great.

```
Function GetScopeFilename(center_wavelength_value As Variant, sweeprate As Variant) As String 
Dim wbSrc As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, position As Long
Dim row_index As Long, CWL_row As Range

Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open("C:\UsersDocuments\LookupTable.xlsx")
Set ws = wbSrc.Worksheets("Scope Filename")

    Set CWL_row = ws.Columns(1).Find(What:=center_wavelength_value, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    row_index = CWL_row.row 
GetScopeFilename = Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup(sweeprate, ws.Range("B1:E3"), row_index, True) 

End Function
```

Here is what my lookup table looks like it just has a bunch of filepath names
[image]

What I am looking for is to see if there is a way for the find function to round down to the next number. Right now I have it set for `False` so it is not case sensitive. Is there a way for it to use the number for `center_wavelength_value` and round down to 1060 and use that cell value with `sweeprate = 50`?

Answer (score 0):

You might return offset value of your Find. The way you use the Find will only find the first instance, as [you don`t trigger any loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find).

You use this:

```
    Set CWL_row = ws.Columns(1).Find(What:=center_wavelength_value, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

MyValue = CWL_row.Offset(0,-1).value
```